# What does working after under contract look like?

Tags: publishing, non-fiction, first-time-author, manuscripts

I worked on a manuscript for many years. During that time, I was independent, so I could make changes and decisions, without documenting or informing or getting permission.

I may soon be working to finish this under contract. How does the process of making changes look? Do I need to keep the publisher constantly in the loop, get permission first, etc.? Is that appropriate or commonplace for the author to present the publisher with his/her own "to do list" of tasks/changes he/she already knows needs to get done?

Comment: I don't have any experience with this, so I can only speculate. But to state the obvious, don't forget to discus this before signing a contract. (If you have an agent, that might be a good person to talk to as well.) The specific process might depend on what sort of manuscript it is (fiction, academic, etc), so it may be worth adding that to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think that it always depends on the company.

The best way is always to ask them about their expectations and what they would expect. This will cut down the following risks:

1. If they do not expect you to constantly asking for permissions, and if you do hat then it may create a negative impression.
2. And yes, the vice-versa.